# Return By Reference as an &Int

Tags: c++, reference, return

So I have this bit of code here:

```
template <class T>
T& Array<T>::operator[](const int pos){
// Exit if pos is not valid.
if (pos < 0 || pos >= mSize) {
    return -1;
}
return mArray[pos];
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'
```

I know it's happening because I have the reference &T at the beginning and I'm returning a -1 if it's not valid through the if statement. As much as I would like to take out the reference, this is a school lab and I can't adjust the prototype. 
So basically my question is: **how do I make it exit as -1 if the if statement goes through without editing any references?** I know I've probably learned this at some point, but I'm having a bit of a brain fart and looking for the last little bit has yielded no results.

Comment: To return a reference you have to have a `T` somewhere (not local to the function) that you can return a reference to. Not a very good interface design though, as this stops you from storing a -1 in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the interface design. For the moment let's ignore some technical details and let's assume that the function that performs the task doesn't return a reference but returns by value. Let's assume also that it is not the operator[] but a function called GetValueAt:

```
template <class T>
T Array<T>::GetValueAt(const int pos)
```

This signature essentially tells the caller "give me a number and I'll return the corresponding element in the array". It's important to distinguish this from another possibility which would be to have a function that says "give me a number, *and if indeed corresponds to an element within the range*, I 'll return that element". In that case the signature could be something like

```
template<class T>
std::optional<T> Array<T>::GetValueAt(const int pos)
```

`std::optional<T>` is a class that may indeed contain an instance of T, or it may contain nothing. This signature, recognizes the fact that the given integer may not fall within the range of the array. It accepts this as a normal use case and it is prepared for it. If the index is not valid, it returns an empty std::optional.

The first signature however says "whatever index you give me, i ll give you back a reference". It doesn't treat the case where the index is out of range as a normal use case but as an unexpected, erroneous situation. The right way to do in this case is to throw an exception, since no returned argument can express correctly what has happened, i.e.:

```
template <class T>
T Array<T>::GetValue(const int pos)
{
if (pos < 0 || pos >= mSize) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("index out of range");
return mArray[pos];
}
```

Note that in this case you are tempted to return -1, but this doesn't express correctly that the index is not valid. -1 in some cases might be a valid value, therefore inappropriate to signal an error.

So to sum up, I would write your method like this:

```
template <class T>
T& Array<T>::operator[](const int pos)
{
if (pos < 0 || pos >= mSize) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("index out of range");
return mArray[pos];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return `-1`. Even if `T` was a type that can be constructed from `-1` you shouldn't return a valid value on a error. How can you differentiate from a successful call and a failed one? Plus what if `T` is a type that can't be constructed from `-1`? E.g. `std::string`

Depending on your iterfaces you have a few options to signal the function couldn't perform its duties:

- throw an exception (the best option)
- add an `assert`. This will end your program in debug mode or cause Undefined Behavior in release.
- call `exit` and end the program

Just for completeness here are some other options, that are more C-ish way of dealing with it. Generally none of them recommended. Go for the exception.

- add an extra parameter (not an option for `operator[]`)
- return a `std::optional`. Complicated further for reference type like in your example (`std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>`)
- return a (possible null) pointer. Not recommenced.
- set a static/global/tread_local variable (like `errno`).